# product of asymptotic standard normal distribution

Tags: convergence, asymptotics, chi-squared-distribution, slutsky-theorem

Suppose $Z_n\xrightarrow{d} Z \sim N(0,I_p)$, why $Z_n^TZ_n\xrightarrow{d}\chi^2_p$?

I encounter this problem when we get the asymptotic distribution of the maximum likelihood estimator (MLE). Suppose $\hat{\beta}$ is MLE of $\beta$, then there exists a matrix $\Sigma$ so that $\Sigma^{-1/2}(\hat{\beta}-\beta)\xrightarrow{d}N(0,I_p)$. Then my class note says "thus, $(\hat{\beta}-\beta)^T\Sigma^{-1}(\hat{\beta}-\beta)\xrightarrow{d}\chi^2_p$". Why is this true? I thought about Slutsky's theorem. However, Slutskty's condition is not for the product of two converge-in-distribution random variables. What am I missing here?

Comment: Your recent questions are all cross-posted on the maths site. Please decide where you want to ask; cross-posting is discouraged in general.

Comment: If $Z_1, Z_2, \dots, Z_k  \stackrel{iid}{\sim}\mathsf{Norm}(0,1),$ then $H =\sum_{i=1}^k Z_i^2 \sim\mathsf{Chisq}(k).$

Comment: @BruceET Thank you. I understand the sum of the square of standard normal is chi-square distribution. What I don't understand is why this is also true in an asymptotic way, namely suppose $Z_n\xrightarrow{d} Z \sim N(0,I_p)$, why $Z_n^TZ_n\xrightarrow{d}\chi^2_p$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This follows from Theorem 5.1.5 of
Lehmann, Erich Leo. Elements of large-sample theory. Springer Science & Business Media, 2004.

He refers to the proof on p. 24–25 of
Serfling, RJ. Approximation Theorems of Statistics. John Wiley & Sons,
New York, NY (1980).

Comment: Thanks. Here is the theorem: if $X_{n}\overset{d}{\rightarrow}X\in\mathcal{R}^k$, then for any continuous function $f$ taking $k$ arguments, we have $$f(X_{n})\overset{d}{\rightarrow}f(X)$$